# Pie chart center click disable

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I clicks on `pieChart chartValueSelected()` method called. But now my need is when I click in center in `pieChartView`, there will be no action perform.

Comment: Which PieChart you are using ?

Comment: donat . (show like circle)

Comment: I guess you are using HighCharts ? And you are referring Donut chart.

Comment: please open this link:- https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts .  and find PieChart (with selection, ...)

Comment: i have done the clickable , but problem is that i want to disable click when user click in center of chart.

Comment: Ah Ok, Can you share some code ?

Comment: i have not reputation, so stack overflow does not allow for chat.

Comment: - (void)chartValueSelected:(ChartViewBase * __nonnull)chartView entry:(ChartDataEntry * __nonnull)entry highlight:(ChartHighlight * __nonnull)highlight
{
    NSLog(@"%@",entry);
\}

Comment: this method call when i click on chart,

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what kind of chart (or Library) you used.

In this situation, the contents of function you written seem not to matter.

So I will explain the general situation.

You can place a transparent button in the middle of the pie-chart.

Then link that button to your "chartValueSelected()" function.

Comment: - (void)setupPieChartView:(PieChartView *)chartView
{
    chartView.usePercentValuesEnabled = YES;
    chartView.drawSlicesUnderHoleEnabled = NO;
    chartView.holeRadiusPercent = 0.58;
    chartView.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0.61;
    chartView.chartDescription.enabled = NO;
    [chartView setExtraOffsetsWithLeft:5.f top:10.f right:5.f bottom:5.f];
    chartView.drawCenterTextEnabled = YES;
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
}